# it shows array outofbound exception

Tags: java, selenium

I want to store it in a Arraylist in the following order :

- topcompany.get(i).getText(),
- avg_exp.get(i).getText(),
- avg_sal.get(i).getText(),
- inlakhs.get(j).getText(),
- circle_text.get(i).getText(),
- inlakhs.get(j+1).getText()

My code:

```
 List<WebElement> topcompany = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//*[name()='svg'])[2]//*[name()='a']//*[name()='text']//*[name()='tspan' and @dy='4']"));
 List<WebElement> avg_exp = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//*[name()='svg'])[2]//*[name()='text' and @x='245']//*[name()='tspan' and @dy='4']"));
 List<WebElement> avg_sal = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//*[name()='svg'])[2]//*[name()='text' and @x='295']//*[name()='tspan' and @dy='4']"));
 List<WebElement> inlakhs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//*[name()='svg'])[2]//*[name()='text' and @fill='#000000']//*[name()='tspan' and @dy='3.5']"));
 List<WebElement> circle_text = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//*[name()='svg'])[2]//*[name()='a']//*[name()='text' and @fill='#ffffff']//*[name()='tspan' and @dy='3.5']")); 

 for(int i=0;i<topcompany.size();i++) {
     for(int j=4;j<inlakhs.size();j++) {
         //main_list.add(new String[] {topcompany.get(i).getText(),avg_exp.get(i).getText(),avg_sal.get(i).getText(),inlakhs.get(j).getText(),circle_text.get(i).getText(),inlakhs.get(j+1).getText()});
     }
 }
```

Comment: inlakhs.get(j+1).getText(), this fragement might be causing it.

Comment: Also if you can properly format the code, it would be much easier to debug it.

Comment: this one showing array outof bound exception

Comment: I agree, this is quite difficult to read and understand what is going on.

Comment: i want to store it inside a arraylist<string[]> {company[0],avgsalary[0],avgexp[0],inlakhs[4],circletext[0],inlakhs[5]

Comment: try to remove inlakhs.get(j+1).getText(), or modify the for loop to : ` for(int j=4;j<inlakhs.size()-1;j++)`

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to understand what you are trying to achieve.

But here is a starting point : If we request for an index that is either negative, or greater than or equal to the size of the array, an **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** is thrown.

In your case, `inlakhs.get(j+1).getText()` is going to throw an error when `j` reaches **`inlakhs.size() - 1`** because then `j` will be equals to the size of the list.

You must fix this first and you will see this error disappears

Answer (score 0):

Your issues is clearly caused by accessing a list with an index out of range. Run the following code to debug and find out what list in particular is causing the exception:

```
    List<WebElement> topcompany = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//*[name()='svg'])[2]//*[name()='a']//*[name()='text']//*[name()='tspan' and @dy='4']"));
    List<WebElement> avg_exp = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//*[name()='svg'])[2]//*[name()='text' and @x='245']//*[name()='tspan' and @dy='4']"));
    List<WebElement> avg_sal = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//*[name()='svg'])[2]//*[name()='text' and @x='295']//*[name()='tspan' and @dy='4']"));
    List<WebElement> inlakhs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//*[name()='svg'])[2]//*[name()='text' and @fill='#000000']//*[name()='tspan' and @dy='3.5']"));
    List<WebElement> circle_text = driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//*[name()='svg'])[2]//*[name()='a']//*[name()='text' and @fill='#ffffff']//*[name()='tspan' and @dy='3.5']"));


    java.util.List<java.util.List<WebElement>> elements = new java.util.ArrayList<java.util.List<WebElement>>();
    for(int i=0;i<topcompany.size();i++)
    {
        for(int j=4;j<inlakhs.size();j++)
        {
            for (java.util.List<WebElement> list : elements) {
                try {
                    WebElement element = list.get(i);
                }
                catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    System.out.printf("%s caused an exception at index %d", element.toString(), i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```